# DJango captcha Error messages getting duplicated

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

my captcha error messages get duplicated
my template error display code:

```
        {% if form.non_field_errors %}
                {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                    <h3 style = "color:red;text-align:center">{{ error }}</h3>
                {% endfor %}
        {% elif messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
                <h3 class = "{% if message.tags == 'success' %} message-green {% elif message.tags == 'error' %} message-red {% endif %}" style = "text-align:center">{{message}}</h3>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
```

and my views:

```
def Insertvalue(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EmpInsertForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.URL = request.POST.get('URL')
            form.email = request.POST.get('email')
            form.save()
            messages.success(request,'Info saved. Be on the lookout for a confirmation e-mail')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Captcha not cleared. Please try again.')
        return render(request,'Index.html',{"form":form})
    else:
        form = EmpInsertForm()
        return render(request,'Index.html',{"form":form})
```

the messages.error is the one that gets duplicated. to reproduce it, I first have to get the non field error which is bascally a unique_together error, and then get the captcha error and it will be printed as many times as I got the non field error + 1. Is there any way to delete all messages in the messages array if non field error is raised? Thank you in advanced.